# Why is my variable not declared in the scope?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, compiler-errors, scope

I'm working on an assignment right now and when run my code returns this error:

```
main.cpp:60:20: error: ‘dataArr’ was not declared in this scope
         if(tolower(dataArr[i].last) == tolower(lastName))
```

I'm not quite sure what I'm missing here. If I could at least get it to run I'd appreciate it. Thanks.
I thought arrays were declared globally so i thought it wouldn't be an issue in my functions

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
struct Database
{
    string first;
    string last;
    string ID;
    string phoneNum;
};
void lastSearch(string);
void idSearch(string);
int main()
{
    Database dataArr[100];
    ifstream myFile("library_database.txt");
    int count = 0;
    while(!myFile.eof() && count < 100)
    {
        myFile >> dataArr[count].first >> dataArr[count].last >> dataArr[count].ID >> dataArr[count].phoneNum;
        cout << dataArr[count].first << " " << dataArr[count].last << " " << dataArr[count].ID << " " << dataArr[count].phoneNum << endl;
        count++;
    }  
    int input;
    string search;
    cout << "Would you like to search by last name or member ID?\n1. Last Name\n2. ID\n> ";
    cin >> input;
    while(input != 1 || input != 2)
    {
        cout << "Enter a valid answer.\n> ";
        cin >> input;
    }
    if(input == 1)
    {
        cout << "Enter last name: ";
        cin >> search;
        lastSearch(search);
    }
    if(input == 2)
    {
        cout << "Enter ID: ";
        cin >> search;
        idSearch(search);
    }
    return 0;
}
void lastSearch(string lastName)
{
    int num = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        if(tolower(dataArr[i].last) == tolower(lastName))
        {
            cout << dataArr[i].first << " " << dataArr[i].last << " " << dataArr[i].ID << " " << dataArr[i].phoneNum << endl
            num++;
        }
    }
    if(num == 0)
    {
        cout << "No match was found in the file.";
    }
}
```

voidSearch was removed to allow this to be posted

Comment: Your array "dataArr" is not a global array, and is only an array declared inside the main() function. That is the reason the lastSearch() function does not know the "dataArr", which causes the compile error.

Comment: You declare `dataArr` in function `int main()` so it can only be used in `int main()` - that is its scope. You probably need to pass it as a parameter to the functions you want to use it.

Comment: Nothing (I’m aware of) is declared implicitly as globally.

Comment: @Taekahn: I suspect, technically, an item declared at the top of a file (outside any function) could be considered implicit global. At least within the confines of the file, anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

To answer the title of your post: because it isn't.

You declare `dataArr` in `main`, but you are trying to use it in `lastSearch`, so `lastSearch` can't see it.  But you can pass it in as a parameter, that's probably the easiest fix:

```
void lastSearch(const string lastName, const Database *dataArr) { ... }
```

and call it like this:

```
lastSearch (search, dataArr);
```

Note the use of `const` (get into the habit of doing that whenever you can) and that your array 'decays' to a pointer when you pass it as a parameter like this, so don't be tempted to use `sizeof` in `lastSearch`.  If you need to know the number of elements in the array, pass that as a parameter too.

Or, better, use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead of a C-style array and then the size of the array *is* available in `lastSearch` without the need to pass it in separately.  If you do that, you probably want to pass it by `const` reference to avoid copying it every time you call the function.

Finally, it might be time to learn about [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).  At the expense of a little more complexity (but not much), this would avoid the need to allocate a fixed size array.  Again, for the same reason, pass it around by reference.

---

Some bedtime reading: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Well, I would say the *easiest* fix is to just move the declaration up two lines (before `main`), at least in terms of editor keystroke count :-) But, as per both our answers, `easy != right`. And vector is probably much better here since this arbitrary size of 100 is a bad idea. While OP collects the actual size, they still use `100` in the search function, though they may have read far fewer.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are not declared globally, they are declared where you declare them :-)

In your case, you declare it at the top of `main()` so that is its scope, from point of declaration to end of `main()`. Trying to use it in `lastSearch()` is therefore invalid.

The *easiest* fix is probably just to move the declaration immediately before `main()` so that it *is* global. But the easiest things is often not the right thing.

You would be better off embracing C++ fully<sup>(1)</sup> and using something like `std::vector`, whose size isn't arbitrarily limited to `100` (for example) and which you could pass around quite easily, something like:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void function(const std::vector<int> &vec) {
    std::cout << vec.size() << ' ' << vec[0] << '\n'; // Output: 2 42
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> x;
    x.push_back(42);
    x.push_back(99);
    function(x);
}
```

The main advantages with vectors are that:

- you're not limited to a maximum of 100 items;
- you don't have to pass around the *actual* count of items read separately as with a raw array or even a `std::array` (you don't do that in your code but I assure you, that's a problem).
- the size of the vector is an integral property of the vector, available anywhere the vector is in scope.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> There's a variety of developers I like to call `C+` developers. These are the people that, though they claim to be C++ developers, have never really embraced the C++ way of doing things, sticking to C style programming practices like non-smart pointers or normal arrays :-)

Some of those things may still have a place in modern C++ code but you should be circumspect in their use.